# 2 different login screens ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, login-screen

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04,
since then, when I login after reboot I get the default ubuntu login screen, and when I login after lock/sleep I get gnome login screen (Small rectangle with password field)

I want to get the default login screen after lock too...

I've searched the internet and I found a similar issue but on ubuntu 15.*, and the solution didn't work

Comment: I want to add that I changed the login screen to gray GNOME default intentionally because I hate the purple with gdm3 update-alternatives, but my wake from sleep/lock login screen is still the old purple!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Managed to fix it by uninstalling GDM3, and everything seems to still work fine, but I'm not a Linux expert

Comment: You uninstalled gdm3 and installed something else instead? anyway, I think you just switched to lightdm or something else without knowing it because otherwise you only saw console when you rebooted. And it should solve this problem (switching to lightdm) because you switched from the gnome display manager (gdm) to another one, but I want to keep this display manager and solve the problem with it